# Volume OSD in Lubuntu

Tags: sound, lubuntu, lxde, volume-control, notify-osd

When I change volume, either with shortcut keys on keyboard or with mouse on system setting, how can I get a notification on screen showing the current audio level?

Maybe I can use xfce volume OSD ?

[image]

I am using Lubuntu 16.04

Comment: did you find something ?